# SQL Server 2008: Unexpected results using SELECT TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone explain the SQL Server 2008 behaviour I'm seeing?

Given a simple table definition:

```
Column          Type          Nullability
id (PK)         int           not null
author_id       int           null
title           varchar(255)  not null
body            varchar(MAX)  not null
type            varchar(255)  null
comments_count  int           null
```

"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY comments_count DESC" returns:

```
id  author_id  title                               comments_count
--- ---------- ----------------------------------- --------------
1   1          Welcome to the weblog               2             
2   1          So I was thinking                   1             
3   0          I don't have any comments           0             
4   1          sti comments                        0             
5   1          sti me                              0             
6   1          habtm sti test                      0             
7   2          eager loading with OR'd conditions  0
```

but "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM posts ORDER BY comments_count DESC" returns:

```
id  author_id  title                               comments_count
--- ---------- ----------------------------------- --------------
1   1          Welcome to the weblog               2             
2   1          So I was thinking                   1             
4   1          sti comments                        0
```

instead of returnsing row IDs 1, 2 and 3 as I would expect.

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 15):

The rows with id 3 and 4 have a tie when ordered by the `comments_count` column.  Standard SQL says that it's up to the vendor implementation to determine sort order if there's a tie or if you don't specify any `ORDER BY` clause.

I suggest you specify the order if you want a certain order:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM posts ORDER BY comments_count DESC, id ASC
```

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that if you don't explicitly specify an ordering then it isn't even guaranteed to be consistent across different runs of the query. Next time the third row could be any of the IDs from `3` to `7` if `ID` isn't included in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Luke: I think you just did mention it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Seems like a common misconception amongst non-DBA folk like myself.